# regular expression - non-subdomain subdirectory (https or http) to https://www

Tags: regex

I can't seem to nail this regular expression:

Currently I have:

https://example.com/forums/  (1000's of pages)

I need to move to

https://www.example.com/    (1000's of pages)

In addition, if coming in on non-ssl, need to move to ssl. All via 301. So as another example:

http://example.com/forums/somepage.html goes to https://www.example.com/somepage.html

and

https://example.com/forums/folder/folder2/anything goes to https://www.example.com/folder/folder2/anything

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can we get more specifics?  What is this regex for?  If it's for some web server rewrite rules, tell us what web server it is because there may be an easier way to do it than you are doing.

Comment: This is for vbulletin forum.

Comment: so will be php/mysql

Answer (score 0):

This will match all of your requested routes (good or no good) and reroute them to the good ones you want. Depending on your regex parser, you may need to throw in some escapes (`\`) in there.

```
s#http(s)?://(www.)?example.com/(forums/)?#https://www.example.com/#g

  http                                       -- match http
      (s)?                                   -- match with or without the s
          ://                                -- match ://
             (www.)?                         -- match with or without www.
                    example.com/             -- match example.com/
                                (forums/)?   -- match with or without forums/
```